# Reduce tracking window using google mlkit vision samples

Tags: android, kotlin, google-vision, google-mlkit

I would like to reduce the reduce bar code tracking window when using the google vision api. There are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405717/android-vision-reduce-bar-code-tracking-window/36428822#36428822) but they feel a bit outdated.

I'm using google's sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

Currently, I try to figure out if a barcode is inside my overlay box inside [BarcodeScannerProcessor](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/kotlin/barcodescanner/BarcodeScannerProcessor.kt) `onSuccess` callback:

```
override fun onSuccess(barcodes: List<Barcode>, graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay) {
    if(barcodes.isEmpty())
      return;

    for(barcode in barcodes) {
      val center = Point(graphicOverlay.imageWidth / 2, graphicOverlay.imageHeight / 2)
      val rectWidth = graphicOverlay.imageWidth * Settings.OverlayWidthFactor
      val rectHeight = graphicOverlay.imageHeight * Settings.OverlayHeightFactor

      val left = center.x - rectWidth / 2
      val top = center.y - rectHeight / 2
      val right = center.x + rectWidth / 2
      val bottom = center.y + rectHeight / 2

      val rect = Rect(left.toInt(), top.toInt(), right.toInt(), bottom.toInt())

      val contains = rect.contains(barcode.boundingBox!!)
      val color = if(contains) Color.GREEN else Color.RED

      graphicOverlay.add(BarcodeGraphic(graphicOverlay, barcode, "left: ${barcode.boundingBox!!.left}", color))
    }
}
```

Y-wise it works perfectly, but the X values from `barcode.boundingBox` e.g. `barcode.boundingBox.left` seems to have an offset. Is it based on what's being calculated in [GraphicOverlay](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/GraphicOverlay.java)?

I'm expecting the value below to be close to 0, but the offset is about 90 here:

[image]

Or perhaps it's more efficient to crop the image according to the box?

Comment: can you please share full working code to filter results which is inside overlay ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the bounding box is correct. The trick is that the image aspect ratio doesn't match the viewport aspect ratio so the image is cropped horizontally. Try to open settings (a gear in the top right corner) and choose an appropriate resolution.

For example take a look at these two screenshots. On the first one the selected resolution (1080x1920) matches my phone resolution so the padding looks good (17px). On the second screenshot the aspect ratio is different (1.0 for 720x720 resolution) therefore the image is cropped and the padding looks incorrect.

[image: 720x720]
[image: 1080x1920]

So the offset should be transformed from image coordinates to the screen coordinates. Under the hood `GraphicOverlay` uses a matrix for this transformation. You can use the same matrix:

```kotlin
    for(barcode in barcodes) {
      barcode.boundingBox?.let { bbox ->
        val offset = floatArrayOf(bbox.left.toFloat(), bbox.top.toFloat())
        graphicOverlay.transformationMatrix.mapPoints(offset)

        val leftOffset = offset[0]
        val topOffset = offset[1]

        ...
      }
    }
```

The only thing is that the `transformationMatrix` is private, so you should add a getter to access it.

Comment: Ah I see. I use 640x480 at the moment, which seems to be a good balance between performance and accuracy with the phones I've tried. Do you know how compensate for the potential aspect ratio difference in the callback?

Comment: @filur Please take a look at the updated answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up with an approach similar to @aminography's answer. But you were first and you're also right so I'll award this answer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

As you know, the preview size of the camera is configurable at the settings menu. This configurable size specifies the `graphicOverlay` dimensions.

On the other hand, the aspect ratio of the `CameraSourcePreview` (*i.e.* `preview_view` in [`activity_vision_live_preview.xml`](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_vision_live_preview.xml)) which is shown on the screen, does not necessarily equal to the ratio of the `graphicOverlay`. Because depends on the size of the phone's screen and the height that the parent `ConstraintLayout` allows occupying.

So, in the preview, based on the difference between the aspect ratio of `graphicOverlay`  and `preview_view`, some part of the `graphicOverlay` might not be shown horizontally or vertically.

There are some parameters inside `GraphicOverlay` that can help us to adjust the left and top of the barcode's boundingBox in such a way that they start from 0 in the visible area.

First of all, they should be accessible out of the `GraphicOverlay` class. So, it's just enough to write a getter method for them:

**GraphicOverlay.java**

```java
public class GraphicOverlay extends View {
    
    ...

    /**
     * The factor of overlay View size to image size. Anything in the image coordinates need to be
     * scaled by this amount to fit with the area of overlay View.
     */
    public float getScaleFactor() {
        return scaleFactor;
    }

    /**
     * The number of vertical pixels needed to be cropped on each side to fit the image with the
     * area of overlay View after scaling.
     */
    public float getPostScaleHeightOffset() {
        return postScaleHeightOffset;
    }

    /**
     * The number of horizontal pixels needed to be cropped on each side to fit the image with the
     * area of overlay View after scaling.
     */
    public float getPostScaleWidthOffset() {
        return postScaleWidthOffset;
    }
}
```

Now, it is possible to calculate the left and top difference gap using these parameters like the following:

**BarcodeScannerProcessor.kt**

```kotlin
class BarcodeScannerProcessor(
    context: Context
) : VisionProcessorBase<List<Barcode>>(context) {

    ...

    override fun onSuccess(barcodes: List<Barcode>, graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay) {
        if (barcodes.isEmpty()) {
            Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "No barcode has been detected")
        }

        val leftDiff = graphicOverlay.run { postScaleWidthOffset / scaleFactor }.toInt()
        val topDiff = graphicOverlay.run { postScaleHeightOffset / scaleFactor }.toInt()

        for (i in barcodes.indices) {
            val barcode = barcodes[i]
            val color = Color.RED
            val text = "left: ${barcode.boundingBox!!.left - leftDiff}   top: ${barcode.boundingBox!!.top - topDiff}"
            graphicOverlay.add(MyBarcodeGraphic(graphicOverlay, barcode, text, color))
            logExtrasForTesting(barcode)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

#### Visual Result:

Here is the visual result of the output. As it's obvious in the pictures, the gap between both left & top of the `barcode` and the left and top of the visible area is started from 0. In the case of the left picture, the `graphicOverlay` is set to the size of `480x640` (aspect ratio ≈ 1.3334) and for the right one `360x640` (aspect ratio ≈ 1.7778). In both cases, on my phone, the `CameraSourcePreview` has a steady size of `1440x2056` pixels (aspect ratio ≈ 1.4278), so it means that the calculation truly reflected the position of the `barcode` in the visible area.

(note that the aspect ratio of the visible area in one experiment is lower than that of `graphicOverlay`, and in another experiment, greater:  1.3334 < 1.4278 < 1.7778. So, the left values and top values are adjusted respectively.)

[image]
    [image]

Comment: Thanks, I actually went with this solution last night and it works well. However, @ValeriyKatkov was also correct and he answered earlier, also he has less points so I'll award him. Hope that's ok! Thank you for your time